# Manage the value of $m,n$ in between $0$ and $1$ in the following equations.

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Let us consider the equations $$ax+by=m$$ $$cx+dy=n.$$ I have values for $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(x,y)$.
 Then clearly I got the values $(m,n)$. But what I need to do, I want the values $(m,n)$ in between $(0,1)$, that is, both of $m,n$ must lie in the interval $(0,1)$. But I can only change the values of $x$ and $y$, and the values for $(a,b,c,d)$ is given constant, cannot be changed. And also $(m,n)$ is unknown for us. So how can I manage $x,y$ so that $m,n \in (0,1)$?
Basically I can use the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ which takes value from $0$ to $1$, but I cannot understand where to use this function, since $m,n$ are unknown to us and only we can tune the value of $x,y$.
I can do it by trial but what if there are $100$  equations instead of $2$?
Please help me to solve this in general.
Thanks.

Comment: If $x,y$ can be any reals, then as long as the determinant of the coefficient matrix formed by rows [a,b] then [c,d] is nonzero, you can pick any $m,n$ you wish and solve.

Comment: @coffeemath. No sir I cannot pick $m$, $n$ since I have to find them. I have values for $a,b,c,d$ fixed and values for $x$ and $y$ which can be change as I want, but for any given values for $x,y$ how can I change $x,y$ so that $m,n \in (0,1)$? Non-zero determinant of the coefficient matrix is okay, but I want to find the procedure for changing the value of $x,y$ so that the  upcoming values $m,n \in (0,1).$

Comment: So how many variable are there, two or four? You say you have to find m,n so they seem to be variables. You also say you can change x,y as you want, so they also seem to be variables.

Comment: @coffeemath. Basically I have $(a,b,c,d)$ fixed. And I have $(x,y)$ for which I have corresponding $(m,n)$. Now I have to change $(x,y)$ so that the corresponding $(m,n) \in (0,1) \times (0,1)$. But I do not know the value of $m$ and $n$ so we can not choose $m$ as $.2$ and $n$ as $.9$ and proceed. Basically for the given $x,y$ let $(m,n)=(33,85.2)$. Now how can I change $x$ and $y$ so that the renewed value of $(m,n) \in (0,1) \times (0,1)$? I only can change the value for $x$ and $y$. Not only for two variable. I want a method for multivariable $(n)$.

Comment: It might help possible responders if you sketched some application your question has... would give some idea of what you're trying to do. [still seems a bit vague to me]

Comment: Let us consider the equation $AX=Y$ where $A$ is known to us. Now somebody gives me $X$ and then I have got the corresponding $Y$ matrix, now I want all the entries of $Y$ in $(0,1)$ but there must be a relation on previous $Y$ and the recent $Y$ like the bijection $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$. So to get this $Y$, I
can only change the entries of $X$. So I want any procedure so that I can change $X$  suitably.